# Foreach loop with multiple posts is only displaying the latest in array

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

**Problem** Foreach loop is only displaying the first post of the array.

I have a WordPress `get_posts` query set up to fetch `reviews` (custom post type) assigned to the **current customer**, like so:

```
// Get all reviews 

$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'reviews',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order'       => 'ASC',
  'orderby'     => array(
    'date' =>'DESC',
    'menu_order'=>'ASC',
  ),

  /* But only those assigned to the current customer */

  'meta_query'  => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'customer',
      'value'       => '"'.$current_user_id.'"',
      'compare'     => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);

$reviews = get_posts( $args );

?>
```

When I output `echo print_r($reviews)` it will print out multiple matching posts, however, when trying to display those same posts with a `foreach` loop it will only display the latest post in the array...

```
<?php foreach ( $reviews as $review ) : ?>

<li>Content is here...</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more code, for example this is working:

```
<?php

$reviews = [
    ['name' => 'Name 1'],
    ['name' => 'Name 2'],
    ['name' => 'Name 3'],
    ['name' => 'Name 4'],
    ['name' => 'Name 5'],
];

?>

<?php foreach ( $reviews as $review ) : ?>

<li>Content is here...  <?php echo $review['name'] ?> </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, simply pasting the above code into mine it displayed fine, which lead me to believe it was something inside the foreach that was breaking the query... Turns out I had a variable missing which meant the loop would stop and not show the subsequent items of the loop. Cheers.